# Custom hashCode implementation for ConcurrentSkipListMap doen't work as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

The idea is to allow `ConcurrentSkipListMap` to store only one `ApprovalRequest` which has unique `customerId` and its state is `PENDING`. I supplied overridden `hashCode` and `equals` implementations. Moreover, in unit test the `ApprovalRequest` suppose to create a new instance using lombok's `@Builder`. How to make it work?

```
@Component
public class LoanRepository {
private final ConcurrentSkipListMap<ApprovalRequest, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Decision>> pendingStorage;


public synchronized void saveAsPending(final LoanApprovalRequest loanApprovalRequest) {
        log.info("Trying to save: {}", loanApprovalRequest);

        if (pendingStorage.containsKey(loanApprovalRequest)) {
            log.error("Attempt to save duplicate pending LoanApprovalRequest: {}", loanApprovalRequest);
            throw new BusinessRuleException("Attempt to save duplicate pending LoanApprovalRequest: " + loanApprovalRequest);
        }

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Decision> decisions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        for (Approver approver : loanApprovalRequest.getApprovers()) {
            Decision pendingDecision = Decision.builder()
                    .customerId(loanApprovalRequest.getCustomerId())
                    .approverUsername(approver.getName())
                    .state(PENDING)
                    .build();
            decisions.put(approver.getName(), pendingDecision);
        }

        if (pendingStorage.putIfAbsent(loanApprovalRequest, decisions) == null) {
            log.info("Successfully added new LoanApprovalRequest: {}", loanApprovalRequest);
        } else {
            log.error("Save failed. Duplicate LoanApprovalRequest: {}", loanApprovalRequest);
            throw new BusinessRuleException("Fail to add LoanApprovalRequest. Duplicate LoanApprovalRequest: " + loanApprovalRequest);
        }

        log.info("New storage size: {}", pendingStorage.size());
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
ConcurrentSkipListMap<ApprovalRequest, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Decision>> pendingStorage;
@BeforeEach
    public void each() {
        mainStorage = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        pendingStorage = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        repository = new LoanRepository(mainStorage, pendingStorage, threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }

@Order(2)
    @Test
    public void givenTwoProducers_whenSaving30LoanApprovalRequestsConcurrently_expectCorrectStatistics() throws InterruptedException {
        final int numberOfThreads = 2;
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        CountDownLatch completedThreadCounter = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);
        CountDownLatch readyThreadCounter = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);
        CountDownLatch callingThreadBlocker = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Runnable producer1 = () -> {
            try {
                readyThreadCounter.countDown();
                callingThreadBlocker.await();
                Set<Approver> approver = new HashSet<>();
                approver.add(new Approver("Under €1_000 Approver"));
                LoanApprovalRequest request;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    request = LoanApprovalRequest.builder()
                            .customerId("1X-XXXX-XAX")
                            .decisionState(PENDING)
                            .loanAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(123.01 + i))
                            .approvers(approver)
                            .timestamp(ZonedDateTime.now())
                            .build();
                    try {
                        repository.saveAsPending(request);
                    } catch (BusinessRuleException be) {
                        System.out.println(be.getMessage());
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(i * 10L);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                interruptedException.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                completedThreadCounter.countDown();
            }
        };

        Runnable producer2 = () -> {
            try {
                readyThreadCounter.countDown();
                callingThreadBlocker.await();
                Set<Approver> approver = new HashSet<>();
                approver.add(new Approver("Under €9_000 Approver"));
                LoanApprovalRequest request;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    request = LoanApprovalRequest.builder()
                            .customerId("2X-XXXX-XWX")
                            .loanAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1023.55 + i * 10))
                            .decisionState(PENDING)
                            .approvers(approver)
                            .timestamp(ZonedDateTime.now())
                            .build();
                    try {
                        repository.saveAsPending(request);
                    } catch (BusinessRuleException be) {
                        System.out.println(be.getMessage());
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(i * 10L);
                }
                completedThreadCounter.countDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                interruptedException.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                completedThreadCounter.countDown();
            }
        };

        executorService.execute(producer1);
        executorService.execute(producer2);

        readyThreadCounter.await();
        callingThreadBlocker.countDown();
        completedThreadCounter.await();
        executorService.shutdown();

        Statistics statistics = repository.getStatistics(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

        
        assertEquals(2, statistics.getCount());
       
    }
```

**LoanApprovalRequest**

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoanApprovalRequest implements ApprovalRequest, Comparable<LoanApprovalRequest> {

    public LoanApprovalRequest(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        this.timestamp = zonedDateTime;
    }

    String customerId;
    BigDecimal loanAmount;
    Set<Approver> approvers;
    ZonedDateTime timestamp;
    DecisionState decisionState;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        LoanApprovalRequest that = (LoanApprovalRequest) o;
        return customerId.equals(that.customerId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return customerId.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LoanApprovalRequest o) {
        return this.timestamp.compareTo(o.timestamp);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoanApprovalRequest{" +
                "customerId='" + customerId + '\'' +
                ", loanAmount=" + loanAmount +
                // ", approvers=[" + approvers.stream().map(Approver::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]" +
                // ", timestamp=" + timestamp.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:nnnnnnnnn").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))) +
                ", decisionState=" + decisionState +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConcurrentSkipListMap` is not based on hash codes, but on ordering/comparisons.

So you will have to use that `customerId` in `compareTo` as well (or supply the Map with a different `Comparator` based on `customerId`). Otherwise it will not be consistent with `equals` and the Map key uniqueness checks won't work.